# DIV 100% within DIV, keeping footer sticky

Tags: html, css

**Goals:**
"page-wrap" (blue background) must extend height of entire page.

Also keep footer at bottom of page.
Footer cannot overlap sidebar/content.

**Problem:**
Adding height:100% to #container causes footer to overlap when window resized, and adds blank space under footer caused by header

I've tried dozens of different configurations, but cannot seem to reach my goals.

http://jsfiddle.net/fZmut/3/

```
<div id="container">    
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="inside">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <p>sidebar</p>
            <p>sidebar</p>
            <p>sidebar</p>
            <p>sidebar</p>
        </div>
        <div id="flow-content"> 
           <p>content</p>
           <p>content</p>
           <p>content</p>
           <p>content</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

css

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
    /* height:100%; */ /* causes footer to overlap when window resized, and adds blank space under footer caused by header */
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0px auto 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
#header{
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;    
}
#page-wrap {
    background: blue;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0px auto 10px;  
    height:100%;    
}
#page-wrap #inside {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-color: gray;
}
#flow-content {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;    
}
#footer {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 430px;
    margin: 0 10px;

    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to put the footer outside of page wrap... like your header

Comment: @Huangism I found it easier to center the footer inside page-wrap.  margin:o auto; wasn't working outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can add 100% to #container and resolve the 2 issues you mentioned:

make the header absolute position to take care of the extra height issue. (but then you'll need to add extra padding to the blue area to accomodate.

also Make the footer display like a table row and its parent table to take care of the overlapping issue:

```
#header{
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;   

    **position:absolute;**
}
#page-wrap {
    background: blue;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0px auto 10px;  
    height:100%;  

    **display:table;
    padding-top:20px;**
}

#footer {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 430px;
    margin: 0 10px;

    **display:table-row**
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fZmut/7/

Comment: display:table-row, beauty.  Unfortunately, if the content is larger than what's displayed, the #container background doesn't extend down. http://jsfiddle.net/fZmut/10/

Comment: and body{background:black;} fixes that. Thank you kindly!